# JavaScript change element position on keyboard button press

Tags: javascript, html, position, keypress

So I want to change element's position by 100 on keyboard button press.
My code:

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    var keyName = event.key;
    if (keyName == "s") {
        console.log(keyName);
        document.getElementById("element").style.top + 100;
    };
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="element">•</div>
```

And the only thing the code does, is sending log to console about pressed key.


EDIT: The element's position is already Absolute

```css
position: absolute;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what you are trying you have to do the folowing:

1. Your element must be `position: absolute` or `position: relative`
2. the `style.top` properie is a [setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set) so you have to set it´s value like `style.top = '100px'`
3. the top value is a string to add 100 on top you need to parse it to a string and then add back the 'px' at the end of the string

```js
document.addEventListener("keypress", (event) => {
    const elementToMove = document.getElementById("element");
    var keyName = event.key;
    if (keyName == "s") {
        elementToMove.style.top = (parseInt(elementToMove.style.top || 0) + 100)+'px';
    };
}, false);
```

```html
<div id="element" style="position: absolute;">•</div>
```

Comment: I only got error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Comment: i moved the code. it is posible that your element don´t exist when document.getElementById("element") is executet. now it get´s evaluated on every keypress

Comment: Still the same error :/

Comment: I will try getting it's current position, converting it to int, adding 100 to it, converting it to string and setting output to element's style.top

Comment: What the Error is saying is that 'document.getElementById("element")' didn´t got a result. So the element isn´t present in the dom or has an other id.

Comment: Oh, I tried rewriting id's and it's working now. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

The top CSS property participates in specifying the vertical position of a positioned element. It has no effect on non-positioned elements. Make sure your element is positioned (absolute, relative, fixed, static etc...).

Your code is buggy here:
`document.getElementById("element").style.top + 100;`
there should be an assignment to element (+100) will not work.

if you want to add margin then do the following:
`document.getElementById("element").style.marginTop = "100px";`